# Css Inline doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a style and an index. I want to display a logo and a text in the same line but I can't. It display in a different line.

Here is the code:

index.php

```
<body>

<div id="headerbar">
    Hello World
</div>

<div id="mainmenu-bar">
    <div id="mainmenu-content">
        <img src="http://www.conceptcupboard.com/resource-centre/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/recycle-logo.gif" height="75" width="75" style="margin-top:5px;">
        <h1>Text that I don't see, because is down</h1>


    </div>

</div>

<div id="content">
    <h1 color="white">Hello World</h1>
</div>

</body>
```

and layout.css

```
@font-face{font-family: Maven Pro; src: url(../fonts/MavenPro-Regular.ttf);}

body{font-family:Maven Pro; background:#ECECEC; border:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align:baseline; margin:0; padding:0;}

#headerbar{height:30px; float:right; margin-right:20px; margin-top:5px;}
#mainmenu-bar{background:#4C84BC; width:100%; height:90px; overflow: hidden;}
#mainmenu-content{margin: 0 auto; width:1000px;}
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/6WYk4/

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: Try `<h1 style='color: white;'>Something here</h1>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Because you dont have inline-block the h1 , by default it display as block. try this:

```
#mainmenu-bar h1{ 
    display:inline-block;
}
```

full example with vertical align:

http://jsfiddle.net/6WYk4/3/

Answer (score 0):

`<h1>` is a block level element. Use a `span` instead :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason they are not side by side is because they are block level elements. You need to add a float.

Also, inline styles are bad habits.

```
<img src="http://www.conceptcupboard.com/resource-centre/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/recycle-logo.gif" class="derp" />

<style type="text/css">
    .derp {
        height:75px;
        width:75px;
        margin-top:5px;
        float:left;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WurrZ/

```
#mainmenu-content img {float:left;}
#mainmenu-content h1 {float:left; width:600px;}
#content {clear:both;}
```

The image and the h1 need floats and the content needs to be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left;` to the `img`'s css